# Android set margine to root relative layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

Hi I am developing android application. I am creating view programatically.In my layout I have relative layout as root element. I tried to set margin to my root relative layout. But I am not able to do that. I tried this in following way:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        rlp.setMargins(100,100,100,100);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent3));

        setContentView(relativeLayout);
    }
}
```

above code add relative layout to my activity. But not considering margins. Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the way you're trying because that's how the Framework works. The root view always takes the whole space, no margins.

What you can do instead is:

- use padding instead (if your layout allows it)
- create a FrameLayout, create the RelativeLayout, create a `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, set the margins on the layout params, set the layout params into the RelativeLayout, add the RelativeLayout into the FrameLayout and add `setContentView(frameLayout)`

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutParams` should be applied on children not the parent itself. The root view for an `Activity` is not a `RelativeLayout`. First of all if you print out `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getClass().getName()` you will find that the root view is a `android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout` which I assume(from the name) is a `FrameLayout` on support-v7 (`AppcompatActivity`). If you look [android support library sources here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/ContentFrameLayout.java) you will see that it is indeed a `FrameLayout`. My idea is that we should try to give our `RelativeLayout`  `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` like so

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```